# Check if Div with specific ID has a certain class

Tags: jquery

In the following code, I wanna find out if the div with id **dia** has the class named **active**

```
<div id="dia" class="wrapper-dropdown-5 active" tabindex="1">
...
</div>
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't seem to work:-

```
console.log($("#dia").hasClass("active"));
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: You're selector appears to be wrong. hasClass works as you expect.

Comment: you also need to correctly close the `class` attribute.. you have forgotten to and it has been merged with the `tabindex` attribute

Comment: Guys, it was a mistake. I corrected the code and it still didn't work. Could you please have a look?

Comment: I am having extreme trouble believing that this would not work. Do you have another `#dia` in the HTML by any chance? And please, don't try to find out with `$("#dia").length`.

Comment: @Faisal You corrected it, and now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/n24sg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mention above, change your selector to reflect **#dia**

```
<div id="dia" class="wrapper-dropdown-5 active tabindex="1">
 ...
</div>
console.log($("#dia").hasClass("active"));
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZKtQ/

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct, but you must close the class tag after active attribute:

```
<div id="dia" class="wrapper-dropdown-5 active" tabindex="1">
...
</div>
```